# Can a mobile app save data about a user without a user giving the permission?

Tags: privacy, cookies, gdpr

Is it allowed to **store a user id to remember him, his settings, preferences and history, without asking for his permission?**

Is there anyknowledge about that how that goes with privacy laws like GDPR or Californian privacy laws?

I'm mostly interested in mobile apps, but how do mobile and web differ in this aspect?

Comment: This appears to be a legal or compliance question, rather than user experience. You might wish to remove it and post it on a Stack Exchange about law.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where the data is saved. Locally, there shouldn't be an issue I don't think, but if it is saved in the "cloud", then you may need to provide a solution to delete it there as well. Part of the difference is the assumption that the mobile device is not shared, why a website can be accessed via a variety of methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "mobile device is not shared"?